# Error: Exception has occurred. ProviderNotFoundException (Error: Could not find the correct Provider<List<FBUser>> above this CustList Widget

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, dart, mobile

The error happened when I created the 2 dart files below and I have reviewed my code over and over and I still can't find a solution to the error. If anyone can explain where I went wrong and how I can fix the error it would be much appriciated.

I can provide more code or more files if any of the code down below isn't clear.

cust_list.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:subitemtracker/models/user.dart';
import 'package:subitemtracker/screens/home/cust_tile.dart';

class CustList extends StatefulWidget {

@override
_CustListState createState() => _CustListState();
}

class _CustListState extends State<CustList> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

// error is on the line of code below
final custs = Provider.of<List<FBUser>>(context); //(add double 
"??", do this on home.dart too)

return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: custs!.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return CustTile(cust: custs[index]);
  },
);
}
}
```

cust_tile.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:subitemtracker/models/user.dart';

class CustTile extends StatelessWidget {

final FBUser cust;
CustTile({ required this.cust });

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
  child: Card(
    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 6.0, 20.0, 0),
    child: ListTile(
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        radius: 25.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        title: Text(cust.uid),
        subtitle: Text('First subscription'),
    ),
  )
);
}
}
```

Comment: where are you placing CustList widget ? share the detailed code

Comment: at the bottom of cust_list.dart